# Which directories are writable by web server on shared web-hosting?

Tags: php, directory, shared-hosting, writable

Currently I'm using shared webhost (Linux) to host my site. I know that anything inside '~/home/my_user_name/www' directory is writable by server. What are the other locations? Basically I want to change default session storage location and probably I shouldn't put it inside www directory.

**Edit**

Does session saving location has to be web server writable, since session is saved by PHP process?

**EDIT 2**

How could I give read+write privilege to Apache on `/home/my_user_name/tmp` directory (tmp dir is outside www directory)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real "standard" for directories that could be writable by the httpd server : it all depends on which access-rights have been given by the user who owns the directories.

Temporary session files are generally stored in the `/tmp` directory, which is generally writable by anyone -- but this means your sessions files will be in a directory accessible by other applications and users that are using the same server as you.

As you are running your application from the `/home/my_user_name/www` directory, a solution might be to create another directory, such as `/home/my_user_name/tmp`, and give read+write privilege to Apache on this directory -- and, then, configure your application/php so that session files are stored there.

Another solution would be to store the session data in a database : chances are you have a database that other users and applications on your server can't access.

Comment: @pascal: how would I give read+write privilege to Apache on tmp directory? Apache would come under user/group/others? Probably it would come under group, right?

Comment: It depends what directory is considered as "root" by Apache : if it's the `www` one, the `tmp` one that is not "under" the `www` one will not be served by Apache ;;; else, yes, you could use a `.htaccess` file containing something like `Deny from All` to prevent Apache from serving it ;;; to answer your edit : when pages are served by Apache+PHP, there is no real "PHP process" : Apache is the one serving the page, even if it's using PHP to do that.